# Why is my code skipping over the first digit in the array?

Tags: c

When I try printing out the value of 'a' index [0], I do not receive a value.
My input is '1111' and output does not give me anything for index 0. If I make a for loop to print out all elements I only get three elements, '111'.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    char a[4]; 
    char b[4];

    printf("Input the first binary character: \n");

    scanf("%s",a);

    printf("Input the second binary character: \n");

    scanf("%s",b);

    printf("%c",a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Four chars make a very small buffer; it can hold at most three characters. It's a good idea to make that bigger and to also enforce the maximum width in `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",a);`--> atleast, `scanf("%3s",a);`

Comment: Your code work fine... I think there is a problem with  your inputs. Check it here:  http://ideone.com/vIdh8f

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour the OP observes when my input consists of four-digit binary numbers. Even larger numbers produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: arbitrary code execution is probably possible in this program.

Comment: Show the input and output, as @BLUEPIXY mentioned.

Comment: My input is '1111' and output does not give me anything for index 0. If I make a for loop to print out all elements I only get three elements, '111'.

Comment: if you want to input 4 characters, change to  `char a[5]; char b[5];`

Comment: [sigh] another bean-counter in an ocean of beans.  Unlss you are running on a RAM-restricted embedded system, don't declare any char buffers smaller than, say, 256.  Just don't:)

Answer (score 2):

Your input buffers are very small:

```
    char a[4]; 
    char b[4];
```

These buffers can hold at most three characters, because they must also reserve space for the treminating null character.

Input from the user is potentially unsafe; it is very likely that the user doesn't obey the three-character limit. Therefore, you should enforce the limit when you scan the numbers:

```
    scanf("%3s",a);
```

It is probably also a good idea to make the buffer bigger. Even if you don't want to allow binary numbers greater than 7, you should probably read in a larger string and issue a suitable error message if it is longer or it it contains non-binary digits. Note that `scanf` also has a return value. It isn't likely, but the user might end the input stream by pressing Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z. Your code should handle such cases.

Comment: This worked! Thank You for the explanation, that makes so much sense!